# html search form, how do i reduce the URL

Tags: html, forms

I am creating a search for using the GET method at the moment, the problem is even if values are not selected and left at there default value they are sent and visible in the url.

I want to only have values selected in the url rather than every current value of the form, including default of 0.

the url ends up long and nasty:
search.php?search_shop_name=mcdonalds&search_shop_address=&search_total_rating=0&search_shop_comfort=0&search_shop_service=2&search_shop_ambience=0&search_shop_friendliness=0&search_shop_spacious=0&search_shop_experience=0&submit=#legend_total_results

I basically want to tidy up the url, am not actually sure if removing unwanted data is a good process or not, any possible advice on this situation? not sure if am being OCD with the visuals
Thanks

Comment: Doing this looks like asking for trouble since you would would have to make the server and client agree on the default values, making it difficult to maintain.

Comment: so do u suggest i put up with it or just use POST instead then?
Or where you just commenting in general ?

Comment: Could you rename the parameters to make them more friendly?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following. Using JavaScript or jQuery, create a submit function, in that function do a validate search with all fields if they = null then don't include them.

For e.g

```
var search;
 function search(){
   if(input[name=search].val() != null)
   {
     search = "q="+input[name=search].val();
   }

   if(input[name=search_shop_experience].val() != null)
   {
     search += "search_shop_experience="+input[name=ssearch_shop_experience].val();
   }
 }
```

I think you do `.=` or its `+=` .

Comment: is this possible with php? my form then sends a query via php + mysql.
Just abit concerned about users turning off j/s. I am trying not to rely on j/s for functionality if possible.

Comment: Not really as your form is a GET request it really would be best to use JS. look at Google they use JS

Comment: An empty parameter does not mean the same as no parameter.

Comment: no but what i am saying is by using jquery or javascript you can then do a submit once you validate the form and remove all the ones that are not filled in.

Comment: i have tried using your code Russell, but it markers a syntax error on booth lines with: search.=
I am trying to make sense of how the j/s communicates with the html

Comment: try removing the . infront of the = and replace it with = for the first one, then for any of the following searches use +=

Comment: thanks, but still no success. I am using <input> elements, checkbox, text and <select><option>  I have noticed that the checkbox's is the only element that does not send data to the url.

Comment: Sorry i don't actually have this online, I will have to update my free hosting. Soon to buy some hosting as i need a database to store my data and would make it far easier for people to help.